# Python: using function and direct computation give me different result

Tags: python, function, computation

I have a situation where using function I defined to calculate a number gives different result if I compute it directly using the expression. The code is as below

```
def func(x1, θ,zl,a1,a2):
    return θ*(x1*a1*zl + a2*x1)

output: 0.019...

θ*(x1*a1*zl + a2*x1)
output: 0.018...
```

I was wondering if anyone knows what could be the reason for this? Does the Python function and direct expression use different precisions? Thank you a lot!

Comment: Please provide a [mcve] that shows how you're calling the function.

Comment: I just made up some numbers to try it with and I get the same result.

Comment: This is what my test program looks like https://i.stack.imgur.com/lnyo2.png

Comment: @Barmar is right that you need a MRE. Don't give us images. Try using this tool I wrote to improve your question: https://futurecoder.io/course/#question
Then click [edit].

Comment: Thank you all for your help! I actually used an input which comes from an attribute of a class: that class is a bit complex. Let me see if I can figure it out.